# Is there any object-storage standardized protocol for storing data+metadata?

Tags: api, storage, protocols, object-storage, cloud-storage

When it comes to query databases, you can rely on SQL or when exchanging emails you can rely on SMTP.

They are both standards across vendors. We could generalize this to many other "standardized services".

This allows the backing provider of the service to be switched easily. I can change a local MySQL to a managed one, or I can switch an SMTP by another just changing the config of the application without changing the code.

## Question:

When it comes to "store binaries", like for example say a company that needs to store photos sent by users, PDFs sent by providers and phone-call recordings from the quality department...

...when it's about "storing binaries over the net" is there any industry-standard in the form of "key-value-metadata" where the value is the binary, the metadata is a free-object (with possibly info about creation time, who is the creator, context of the creation, etc); and the ID is a function of the content (for example a Sha1 or whatever), that ensures anti-duplication measures by design?

When I say industry-standard I mean that I don't care if "behind" my connecting API, the "real" storage is implemented by a redis or a mysql or a plain-file-system or an S3 from AWS... just something "standard" given by multiple parties, to where I connect to and I can "easily change what's behind" by configuration and change from one storage-provider to another with the same simplicity we change our SMTP for example not caring if there's a sendmail or a postfix behind.

Comment: It seems like S3 API is going to get close to something that we call 'standard' (look through the list of storages that support S3 protocol: http://www.s3-client.com/s3-compatible-storage-solutions.html). But I don't believe that S3 will play the same role for object storages as ANSI SQL for relational databases nowadays.